# Need to convert columns to rows in R

Tags: r, reshape, transpose

I have data that looks like

```
a     b     c
1     5     4
3     6     1
2     5     3
```

I want to convert it to convert all the columns to rows and want an output like

```
r1       r2     r3     r4
a        1       3      2
b        5       6      5
c        4       1      3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: transpose of a matrix.

Comment: Hint:  ....................   `t`  ... for which there are both matrix and dataframe methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can transpose the dataset and convert to `data.frame` with the first column as the row names.

```
m1 <- t(df1)
d2 <- data.frame(r1= row.names(m1), m1, row.names=NULL)
```

EDIT: Included the `row.names` argument in the `data.frame` call (from @Richard Scriven's comment)

Or  as @Ananda Mahto mentioned, we can use `names(df1)` to create the 'r1' column, thereby skipping the creation of an object in the global environment.

```
d2 <- data.frame(r1=names(df1), t(df1))
```

---

Or another option is `melt/dcast`.  We convert the `data.frame` to `matrix`, `melt` to 'long' format and then `dcast` it to 'wide' format.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(as.matrix(df1)), Var2~paste0('r', Var1), value.var='value')
```

Comment: Since the `names` of "df1" would become your "r1", you could skip the creation of `m1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped.