# Rotate Row Cell Values to a Single Column in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows

I can't seem to find anything relevant to my specific problem, so I am asking here.
I have my original dataframe here:

```
Sample#, Fert_A_Mean, Fert_B_Mean, Fert_C_Mean, Fert_D_Mean
1        987,         384,         672,         364
2        567,         845,         398,         243
```

And I'd like to be able to restructure it like this:

```
Sample#, Fert_Mean
1        987
1        384
1        672
1        364
2        567
2        845
2        398
2        243
```

I've found some similar topics on stack-exchange, [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447741/need-to-convert-columns-to-rows-in-r?rq=1)

but using 't()' in this case doesn't seem to work... or I am doing something wrong. Hopefully one of you folks can help me out. Thanks so much. Using R 3.4.1 through R-studio. Any packages you recommend for your methods are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like `gather` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df, key=Fert_Mean, value=value, -Sample)

df2
  Sample   Fert_Mean value
1      1 Fert_A_Mean   987
2      2 Fert_A_Mean   567
3      1 Fert_B_Mean   384
4      2 Fert_B_Mean   845
5      1 Fert_C_Mean   672
6      2 Fert_C_Mean   398
7      1 Fert_D_Mean   364
8      2 Fert_D_Mean   243
```

You can remove the `Fert_Mean` column if you don't want it, and sort by `Sample` to get the ordering in your example.

Comment: Hey Andrew thanks - it definitely comes very close... closer than I have come after quite a lot of work! Is there a way to have it output in a way that is sorted, as per my example above? thanks so much man

Comment: `df2 <- df2[order(df2$Sample, df2$Fert_Mean),]` will sort it by `Sample` then `Fert_Mean`, which I think is the order you want.

Comment: Thanks so much man - you saved me a bunch of time. That sort function is definitely useful